# Djangoesque approach to determining submitter of form

Tags: django

In Django, you can define form classes and have templates render them according to the class fields. However, how do you securely pass in information about the user who submitted the form into the view?

For instance, you can manually hard-code the user into a form field in a template with

```
{{ request.user.username }}
```

However, couldn't anyone just submit their own post request to the form url with any user they wanted in this case?

Is there a "Django approach" to prevent the scenario above from happening and to have the view retrieve information about the user who submitted the form?

Comment: The fact that you are using `request.user` is specifying that you are tracking the "logged_in" user. Moreover, you can access `request.user`  from the view method, which tells you who submitted the form.

Comment: Views always receive the request object as their first argument, and the user is of course available from that.  Django doesn't really do controllers, so I'm not sure where you'd be looking to get the user other than in a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To securely track the submitter of the form,  you can require that a user is logged in in order to submit the form.

As kathikr mentioned, you can use `@login_required` decorator to ensure that a user is logged in to submit the form.  Then you can rely on `request.user` to determine the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

The contrib apps “django.contrib.auth” and “django.contrib.sessions” **are** the standard Django way of doing this.

Have a read through the documentation on the “auth” app in particular:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/